# MongoDB Find items including data from other referenced collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following models:

Foo

```
[{
  a: string
  b: string,
  c: [ObjectId, ref: Bar]
}]
```

Bar

```
[{
  name: string
}]
```

Now, the query condition contains 2 params: *q* = any string and *t* = any string.

The goal is to find Foo items where:

Foo[a] OR Foo[b] contains q OR Foo[c] contains Bar[name] that contains t.
Also q may or may not be defined as well as t may or may not be defined.

I need to include also *limit*, *skip* and *sort*.

Simple *Foo.find(conditions)* + *populate* and *match* won't work here. I guess *aggregate* would work here, but I am not familiar with aggregate yet. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: From the Bar collection i do not see a way to link to the Foo collection, even if you find document that match your criteria. A good idea will be  de-normalization the name field.

Comment: @HanielBaez Reading https://dev.to/damcosset/mongodb-normalization-vs-denormalization and I am not convinced for de-normalization the name field. The downside for that is to keeping in sync data in the other places.

Comment: Consider the write/read ratio when denormalizing. A field that will mostly be read and only seldom updated is a good candidate for denormalization: if you denormalize a field that is updated frequently then the extra work of finding and updating all the instances is likely to overwhelm the savings that you get from denormalizing.

Comment: @HanielBaez When the item "name" from the Bar collection is used only in one place then it's highly likely worth to denormalization. However, I use items from Collection Bar in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi [text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index) to support text search queries on string content.

```
db.Foo.createIndex(
   {
     a: "text",
     cb: "text"
   }
 )
```

For example, you could use the following query to find all Foo containing any terms from the list “mongodb”, “javascript”, and “html”:

```
db.Foo.find( { $text: { $search: "mongodb html javascript" } } );
```